# Promise.all() and setState() react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, setstate

In a component I would like fetch some data from my database using fetch API. When all the data is fetched I would like to change the state of the component using Promise.all():

```
await Promise.all(data).then(
  this.setState({
    isLoading: false
  })
)
```

My problem is that setState() fires before the Promises are resolved. However this code works but then isLoading is an array instead of boolean:

```
this.setState({
  isLoading: await Promise.all(data)
})
```

Does anyone know why? I'm kinda new to React-Native so would love some input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change like this:

```
await Promise.all(data).then((result) => {
   this.setState({
     isLoading: false
   })
 }
)
```

Basically `.then` has a function as parameter so you have to put your `setState` inside an arrow function.

Comment: @AxelSun no worries! If my answer helped you mark it as right, thanks

Answer (score 4):

As you are using `async`/`await`, you shouldn't call `then` at all. If you still wanted to use it, you'd need to pass a callback; but your code really should simply look like the following:

```
await Promise.all(data);
this.setState({
  isLoading: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
then(
  this.setState(...)
)
```

You're calling `setState()` *immediately* and passing its result to `then()` (just like any other function call).

You need to pass a function or lambda to `then()` that calls `setState`.